# Storing Dictionary<string, string> in ASP.NET view state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I'm trying to store a `Dictionary<string, string>` in the ViewState of a custom control I'm developing for ASP.NET 2.0:

```
private Dictionary<String, String> Items
    {
        get
        {
            object d = ViewState["Items"];
            return (d == null ? null : (Dictionary<String, String>)d);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Items"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Accessing it looks like this:

```
public void UpdateData
{
    if (this.Items == null)
        this.Items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    else
        this.Items.Clear();
    //Fill the collection
}
```

When it gets set the first time the page loads, it appears to work fine.  But on subsequent postbacks, the value returned is always null (the first condition always happens).  Debugging shows that it's getting `null` out of the ViewState in the property `get`.

I've done some research and have [found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178652%28VS.85%29.aspx) that classes must implement `IStateManager` to be saveable in ViewState, and the [Dictionary MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) appears to indicate that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not.  But I've stored dictionaries before in ViewState without a problem.  What's going on here?  Was my previous experience a fluke?

UPDATE: I tried adding some test code to the property: `ViewState["ItemTest"] = "foo";` in the `set` and `string test = (string)ViewState["ItemTest"];` in the `get`.  Like the `Dictionary`, it comes out null.  So it doesn't appear to be a problem with the `Dictionary` being serializable.  Also, to clarify, `UpdateData` is called from my `RenderControl` override, which happens after `Page_Load` in the page that contains the control.

Comment: Where are you checking fot the values? I believe the ViewState gets loaded after the `Init` event.

Comment: As in checking for null before returning?  The first time the page loads, there's not going to be a value there.

Comment: Is your control added static or dynamic in your page?

Comment: I've seen people accessing the `ViewState` in the `Init` event of the page and thought you might be trying to do the same.

Comment: @ibram: It's in the markup of the Default.aspx in the VS 2010 project.

Comment: @Greg: if `d` is null, then I believe the cast will throw an exception.  Also, `UpdateData` is called in `RenderControl`, which I'm pretty sure is after `Page_Load`.

Comment: You can use the `Value as Type` operator, it will give null if casting has failed.

Comment: @Dani: perfect, I'll make that change.  Probably improves readability.

Comment: @Mr. Jefferson - casting a null value returns null, it does not throw an exception unless you are casting to a value type. For example `(string)null == null`.

Comment: Does either the control or its containing control disable viewstate? ie., `EnableViewState=false`.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: I didn't set that explicitly either way anywhere.  But there is other ViewState stuff being done in the control that works fine, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store the dictionary in ViewState, but you are attempting to do this too late in the page life cycle. Just as ViewState is loaded after `Init`, ViewState is saved *before* controls are rendered. Move your logic out of `RenderControl` and into another method or event handler earlier in the life cycle, such as `PreRender`.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Items == null)
    {
        this.Items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

You will notice the that object is no longer null on subsequent postbacks as long as ViewState is not being disabled on either the control or its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not accessing the property too early in the page lifecycle as the viewstate is not loaded directly.

From what method (at which point in the page lifecycle) are you requesting this property for the first time?

Comment: It's being called from the `RenderControl` override, which I believe is after `Page_Load`, so it should be there.

Comment: Maybe you should try and simply store a string in the same way, see if that one is also null after a postback. If it's null you probably have a problem with the page lifecycle. If it's not empty that will narrow down the problem.