# Read <li> attributes in code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a list such as:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li id="content_rptGalleryImages_galleryListItem_0" data-imageid="7" data-displayorder="0"></li>
   <li id="content_rptGalleryImages_galleryListItem_1" data-imageid="5" data-displayorder="1"></li>
   <li id="content_rptGalleryImages_galleryListItem_2" data-imageid="4" data-displayorder="2"></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to be able to access each list items `data-imageid` and `data-displayorder` attributes and add these to a dictionary in my code behind, something like: -

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(var li in list.Controls)
{
    //find li
    dict.Add(li.Attribute["data-imageid"], li.Attribute["data-displayorder"]);
}
```

Is what I want to achieve possible? And if not, could you suggest an alternative approach?

edit* Repeater code at request:

```
protected void rptGalleryImages_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        BrandImage image = (BrandImage)e.Item.DataItem;
        HyperLink lnkGalleryImage = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkGalleryImage");
        HyperLink lnkImageUrl = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkImageUrl");
        LinkButton lnkBtnRemoveImg = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkBtnRemoveImg");
        HtmlGenericControl galleryListItem = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("galleryListItem");

        lnkGalleryImage.Text = image.ImageLocation.Substring(image.ImageLocation.LastIndexOf("/")).Replace("/", "");
        lnkGalleryImage.NavigateUrl = image.ImageLocation;

        lnkImageUrl.Text = image.ImageUrl;
        lnkImageUrl.NavigateUrl = image.ImageUrl;

        lnkBtnRemoveImg.CommandArgument = image.ImageLocation;

        galleryListItem.Attributes.Add("data-imageid", image.Id.ToString());
        galleryListItem.Attributes.Add("data-displayorder", image.DisplayOrder.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is thie `Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();` a valid javascript? Looks like java to me.

Comment: Were your list of LIs added dynamically by your rendering?  Or are they added dynamically client side?

Comment: @wagregg The li's are added through a repeater, im reordering these li's on the client side with some jquery

Comment: @DGibbs So where is jQuery code here?

Comment: @Vega The only related jQuery i have is the reordering of li's, I doubt this would help in answering the question

Comment: Not sure about what you want to achieve, but maybe you can just build your dictionary when binding your repeater and store the dictionary in the page viewstate (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6297073/1236044 )

Comment: Could you post the repeater code that generates this output?

Comment: @jbl The user will be able to reorder the generated list items, this updates a display order attribute on the list item itself. I want to read these values (image id + display order) back into a dictionary after the user has saved so that these changes can be persisted in the db

Comment: thx for the answer. I guess your lis updated data values won't be posted back to the server (only form data is). So, client side, you will have to use some jquery to build the dictionnary upon submit and store it in a hidden field, which is what you will process server side.

Comment: @jbl Thanks, I figured something like this might be the solution but couldn't read the hidden field value from my code behind, chrome dev tools was showing an error "cannot access value property of null" < something to that effect. It's as if the hidden field isn't being found at all. Can you pass complex objects/dictionaries through jquery to the code behind? As I was worried I could only pass single values in through a hidden field? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not send the `li` element attributes on post requests, because it is not considered a form post variable. That makes it impossible to retrieve the attribute value on the server when the user saves.

**One option to make it work:**

- Populate a hidden field for every item with the respective order value, and change this value with javascript when the user reorders them.
- When he saves, you grab the value from the hiddenfield of each item and persist on the database.

Comment: I think this might work, have a +1. Not sure how to find the hidden field element in my doc though as it will generate a server id? Could I use clientid or something?

Comment: Yes, it will have both server and client IDs. To grab it on the client side you could use the ClientID HiddenField server property. Or even try to use a different ClientMode for the HiddenField on this case.